# How to not make the "/" invisible when using toString()

Tags: c#, string

I'm having some problems on putting my DateTime into a string when I try to put a "/" on the date on the output it does a tab instead of putting the "/"

```
changeDate_temp = calendarPostPone.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Split(' ');

        showDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(changeDate_temp[2].Trim()), 
            Convert.ToInt32(changeDate_temp[1].Trim()), 
            Convert.ToInt32(changeDate_temp[0].Trim()),
            12, 0, 0);

        Console.WriteLine(showDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy | HH:mm"));
```

Output of the code: [image]

All the code works just not the "`Console.WriteLine(showDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy | HH:mm"));`" at least the way I want it to work..

Comment: i am not able to reproduce this issue, which culture you are using on your machine ?

Comment: What is the goal of `ToString` and/or `Split(' ')` in `changeDate_temp = calendarPostPone.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Split(' ');`? Also was not able to repro, works just fine for me - [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nSwoyx), the same output I get in console. What culture is used on your machine? Also what console settings do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slash will be replaced with the date separator of the current culture.

To force the use of slashes, enclose them in single quotes.

```
Console.WriteLine(showDate.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy | HH:mm"));
```